# jQuery an element with for a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs with `data-image="1"` `data-image="2"` `data-image="3"`.

And I have variable `$img_nubmer`.

I need to take the div's background-image url from element with `data-image = $img_nubmer`.

Something like `$url = $("'.img[data-image="+$img_number+"']").css("background-image")`

How could I do that please?

Comment: `var url = $("img[data-image="+$img_number+"]").prop('src')`

Comment: if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            $img_number = 1;
            $background_next = $(".img[data-image="+$img_number+"]").css("background-image");
            alert($background_next);
        }
But it rerurns undefined

Comment: You need to remove the dot in front of `.img`, you're not looking for a class, but for elements that are `<img />`.

Comment: it was an exemple, i have class img so i need that dot i think

Comment: ok in that case. Try to use `console.log` instead of `alert` when debugging. What does `console.log($("img[data-image="+$img_number+"]"));` output to the console?

Comment: $url = $(".img[data-image='"+$img_number+"']").css("background-image")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
$img_number = 5;  // just an example
$url = $("img[data-image='"+$img_number+"']").css("background-image");  // grab the background property
```

So for a full example:

```js
window.getURL = function() {
  $img_number = $('[type="number"]').val();
  $url = $("[data-image='" + $img_number + "']").css("background-image");
  $url = $url.replace('url(', '').replace(')', ''); // lose the extra details
  alert($url);
}
```

```css
div.image {
  background-image: url('http://graph.facebook.com/205500370/picture?type=large');
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image" data-image="5"></div>
<div>
  <input type="number" value="5" />
  <br>
  <button onclick="getURL()">Get Image URL</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ty wery much that's what i need :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the variable into your selector as such:

```
var img_number = 1;
$('img[data-image="'+img_number+'"]');
```

View [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJPrKa) example